# How to get new Bitmap from Byte Array with IntPtr pointer?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, interop, marshalling

i have a problem with `Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement()` method.

What i want to do, is return `Bitmap object` from `byte[]` array. But first, some code below with explenation what i do.

1. First, i load my `Bitmap` to method that i return `byte[]` array from it:

   ```
    //return tuple with pointer to array and byte[]array   
   public static (byte[], IntPtr) GetByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
   {

       //lockbits 
       BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                                               ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                               bitmap.PixelFormat
                                               );

       int pixels = bitmapData.Stride * bitmap.Height;
       byte[] resultArray = new byte[pixels];

       //copying bytes to array
       Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, resultArray, 0, pixels);

       bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

       //returns array and pointer to it
       return (resultArray, bitmapData.Scan0);
   }
   ```
2. Second, i want to edit that byte array:

   ```
   public static Bitmap Execute(Bitmap bitmap, int[] filter)
   {
       //get byte array from method that i mentioned before with pointer to it
       (byte[] pixelsFromBitmap, IntPtr pointer) = PictureUtilities.GetByteArray(bitmap);

       byte[] newPixels = pixelsFromBitmap;

       int stride = bitmap.Width;

       int height = bitmap.Height;
       int width  = bitmap.Width;

       Parallel.For(0, height - 1, y =>
       {
           int offset = y * stride;
           for(int x = 0; x < width - 1; x++)
           {
               //some stuff i doing with array, not neceserry what im doing here
               int positionOfPixel = x + offset;
               newPixels[positionOfPixel] = (byte)122;
           }

       });

       //copying values from newPixels to pixelsFromBitmap that i get from method GetByteArray() that i mentioned it before
       newPixels.CopyTo(pixelsFromBitmap, 0);

       //copying bytes again
       Marshal.Copy(pixelsFromBitmap, 0, pointer, pixelsFromBitmap.Length);

       //generete new bitmap from byte array
       Bitmap result = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, stride,
                                  bitmap.PixelFormat,
                                  pointer);
       return result;


   }
   ```

After all that process i get an Exception in `Execute()` method: `System.ArgumentException` in line, when i getting new `Bitmap result`.

Could you tell me, what i doing wrong? i want to get a byte array from my bitmap from method (for readability), edit it and return new bitmap depends on my new byte array.

I bet, that i not clearly get, how `Marshall.Copy` works and i get wrong `pointer` to returning `byte array` from `GetByteArray()` method.

Thanks for help

Comment: There are multiple problems with this code, you can't ignore the pixel format and cannot assume the stride is the same as the Width.  The pixel data is only ever a byte[] if it uses 8bpp, that is very uncommon.  Consider to get ahead by picking the fast-and-convenient pixel format, pass 32bppArgb to LockBits().  Now you can store and address the pixels with an int[] array and stride no longer matters.

Comment: Thanks for correct my stride! But even if i correct that, it not answering my question why i get exception in that Bitmap constructor

Comment: The IntPtr becomes invalid as soon as you call UnlockBits().  Consider to get ahead by using LockBits and Marshal.Copy again, now copying the other way around.  Or by not using an array at all and party on the int* directly, more efficient that way.

Comment: Ok, i get it. So there is no efficient way to move byte[] array with pointer from another func? i need to do it in same method that i modify array? I used lock bits before, but i do all stuff (initializing byte[] from bitmap) in one method, now in refactor way i wanted to move that thing away

Comment: You have to throw away what you have and write version 2.  You'll get there.